# Automatic Casting of Default Values on Insert

Tags: macos, homebrew, mariadb

This may be a feature instead of a bug, so I thought to include it on SO instead of MariaDB's Jira.

Yesterday I updated my MariaDB install on Homebrew from 10.1.23 to 10.2.6. All my selects are still working correctly, but now in my legacy app, I get a bunch of errors on inserts where the code is "assuming" MariaDB will set a default value. For example...

```
INSERT INTO table SET 
    email = 'some@email.com', -- varchar
    phone_number = '', -- bigint
    ts = '2017-05-30 23:51:23', -- datetime
    some_val = '689728' -- varchar
```

This code was working fine before, but since I've upgraded I now get the following couple of errors...

Error 1 (is_some_toggle is a tinyint and is not defined in the query above, it is assumed that MariaDB would just insert a 0)

```
Field 'is_some_toggle' doesn't have a default value
```

Error 2 (after I set the default value to is_some_toggle)

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'phone_number' at row 1
```

I'm guessing this is a feature, not a bug. I've looked through their [changelogs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102/) for 10.2 series and I'm not seeing anything jump out, but there's a lot so I could have missed it. I saw a server config for OLD_SQL but that didn't seem to be what I was looking for. Any thoughts?

macOS Sierra 10.12.5 btw

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `some_val` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_some_toggle` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email_code` (`email`(15),`some_val`),
  KEY `phone_number_code` (`phone_number`,`some_val`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like going through the changelog VERY slowly worked for me.

sql_mode was updated as was outlined in [this article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-101-to-mariadb-102/).

```
Option      |    Old default value                               |    New default value
sql_mode    |    NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION     |    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I changed it back to the default and I'm good as gold.